# Swap back & recent button

Tags: motorola-moto-g, android-11

I am using Moto-g30 running Android 11 (Pure-stock ROM with moto bloat). By default it's using three button navigation bar with the following layout
`back; home; recent`

I'm trying to swap the recent & back button for easy right handed accessibility. So far I've tried these possible solutions to change the order.

1. Look inside system settings to change the order. - No Success
2. Use adb command `settings put secure sysui_nav_bar "space,recent;home;back,space"` - No Success

Any other alternative to achieve this without root permissions ?